# iterate over bash command

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I need to process my data (about 400+ files) using linux bash command. I'm trying to find a way to iterate the same command to all of my files.

This is my bash command

```
cat file1.vcf | java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" > file1_filtered.vcf
```

I tried to do this but not successful

```
for f in *.vcf; do echo cat *.vcf | java -jar snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" > filtered.vcf; done
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/
Error: Unable to access jarfile snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/
Error: Unable to access jarfile snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/
```

Comment: It seems you'd be better off sending the file name/path as a command line argument to your Java program and iterating over the lines internally? That appears to be your intention here.

Comment: I can't see a question, but a) `echo` is not needed b) you're missing the `~/` from the path c) this will overwrite `filtered.vcf`, better use something like `> ${f%.vcf}_filtered.vcf` at the end

Comment: Try: `for f in *.vcf; do java -jar snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" < "$f" > filtered.vcf; done`  **Note:** to append to `filtered.vcf;` use `>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I will assume that this command of yours works:

```
cat file1.vcf | java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" > file1_filtered.vcf
```

If that is the case, then we can analyze the differences with the second command:

```
for f in *.vcf; do echo cat *.vcf | java -jar snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" > filtered.vcf; done
```

1. The first command provides the contents of the files as input to the java script.  The second command provides the string `cat` followed by the names of the `.vcf` files as input to the java script.
2. The java scripts are in different locations.

To correct those two issues, try:

```
for f in *.vcf
do
    java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" <"$f" > filtered.vcf
done
```

Where I have also removed a useless use of cat.

Lastly, the above overwrites `filtered.vcf` each time a file is processed.  If you want one file to contain all the results, then try:

```
for f in *.vcf
do
    java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" <"$f"
done > filtered.vcf
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. This worked but it replaced the final file so I only get one file at the end. But I managed to fix it using  > ${f}_filteredc.vcf

Answer (score 1):

Your Java program seems to read input line by line. So, if you are not interested in having your output in one file per input file, you can skip the for loop altogether:

```
cat *.vcf | java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ filter " ( QUAL >= 30 )" > files_filtered.vcf
```

This has the added benefit of the `cat` actually concatenating files, for once.

Comment: I get the Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/jannahS/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar/ when I use the above command

Comment: That's strange. I don't understand how this doesn't work if your first command does work.